# Is there a GUI version of nmap available?

Tags: software-recommendation, nmap

Is there a GUI version for nmap that can be installed without manually downloading the program?

I don't have a problem with doing so, but it would be nice if there is one available in the repositories, or by adding a repo.

Comment: here is full installation guide you can prefer : [Nmap Installation](http://www.nmaptutorial.com/install-nmap-in-linux-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Zenmap

You can use `zenmap`, it is in the repository

```
sudo apt-get install zenmap
```

[Here is its website](https://nmap.org/zenmap/) I think it is the official GUI as the site is `nmap.org`.

[image]

## Umit

If you don't like that one try `umit`, it is in the repository as well

```
sudo apt-get install umit
```

This one did not have its own website, here is its [source forge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/umit/)

[image]

## nmapsi4

Finally there is `nmapsi4` too, this seems the best looking one, if you are in to that

```
sudo apt-get install nmapsi4
```

Again no website, but [here is its launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/nmapsi4)

[image]

## Others

There are at least two more available, including a python one and a web interface but this is getting a bit long, to find them yourself, run this command

```
apt search nmap
```

Comment: Helpful, interesting and useful information ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thanks, I found even more now:)

Comment: @DevRobot You are welcome :)

Comment: Great collection - i enhanced the readability  a bit ...hope it's ok

Comment: nmapsi4 now has a website: https://github.com/nmapsi4/nmapsi4

Comment: Zenmap was removed from debian (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=zenmap&searchon=names) and thus Ubuntu (see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233840/has-zenmap-vanished-from-20-04#answer-1233847). Umit is also not provided by either (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=umit&searchon=names). This leaves nmapsi4, as the only gui, unless you want to compile it yourself.