# Is there a Linux utility for monitoring hosts with GUI?

Tags: software-recommendation, ping, network-monitoring

I need a program for **Linux desktop** to monitor hosts with GUI. Like [PingInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multiple_ping_tool.html) for Windows. Or [10-Strike Network Monitor](http://www.10-strike.com/network-monitor/).

What would you recommend?

Please, before you answer view functionality PingInfoView and 10-Strike Network Monitor.

Comment: "Please, before you answer view functionality PingInfoView and 10-Strike Network Monitor." What? If you want good recommendations, **you** should list the features you need.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best tools for network exploration (and security auditing) is [nmap](https://nmap.org). This is a command line tool. People using this tool (without a GUI) are usually either hackers or network security experts.

For a list of GUIs based on nmap, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717273/is-there-a-gui-version-of-nmap-available).

Comment: I need automatic network monitoring tool with GUI and alerts. I don't need network exploration and security auditing.

Answer (score 0):

I like **jNetMap**. It has a full GUI. It's in the repositories. The project's home page is at http://www.rakudave.ch/jnetmap/?file=introduction.

You might also look at **zenmap**. It's a GUI frontend for the powerful nmap.

Comment: Thank you. It's an interesting program, but not what I need. I need to check on the availability of external hosts.

Comment: And internal too :)

Comment: I think jNetMap will do both. Try it, and if it works for you, vote/accept my answer. Cheers, Al

Comment: I tried in this app to add a workstation, but there is no way to add its IP address

Comment: Explain to me how for example to add a host 8.8.8.8 and periodically ping it?

Comment: ZENMAP already offered. This is not what I need

Comment: In jNetMap, right-click on the connection line, or the device icon, and you can set the IP, the icon, etc. Give it more than a 5 minute test. Look at the website for more examples. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really involve discovery so I don't know that nmap is what you are looking for.

If you just need to ping I suggest something like [NMIS](https://opmantek.com/network-management-system-nmis/), it's an open source solution that uses fping.  It can also monitor servers/devices using SNMP (and the newest version also does WMI).

[Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) may also solve your problem, it really depends on what you mean by GUI.

Comment: Thank you. But I need the monitoring software for my Linux workstation. NMIS is server software. I need apps like PingInfoView and 10-Strike Network Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

NMap does not have an GUI. You can check pandora fms. You can get the [open](http://pandorafms.org) version or the [enterprise](https://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/network-monitoring/). I Know both of them and for monitoring some linux hosts open version is more than enough.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't need server software. I need sofware for my Linux desktop. Please see examples PringInfoView or 10-Strike Network Monitor.

Comment: Hi @cyberwatcher, I don't know a similar solution in linux. Sorry. However, why don't you use a server monitoring tool? You can use an easy server monitoring tool to install for free and configure it to map your hosts and get the status.....of course you can't get the monitor integrated in your desktop, but you will be able to use a mobile app or a web browser....configure alerts to your email or mobile phone...Maybe there is a solution that integrates the monitoring status in linux desktops... Good luck

Comment: Thank you, but I already have nice server solution for host monitoring with SMS and e-mail alerts. I just wanted a little program for a quick overview my servers.