# Zenmap for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: nmap

Is `zenmap` available for `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` with `nmap 7.80`? I've already try the instruction at the following link: [Has zenmap vanished from 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233840/has-zenmap-vanished-from-20-04) but packages are not available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has zenmap vanished from 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233840/has-zenmap-vanished-from-20-04) I have just updated the links.

Comment: Thanks it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accord to [this](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2022) from nmap devs;

> Zenmap is not in the ubuntu repository anymore because is not
> compatible pyhton3-gtk3 we have to wait until they use PyGObject who
> replace pygtk and is compatible python3.
> #1176